# A few questions(Bounce, Align)

Tags: jquery, css, center, vertical-alignment, bounce

Im trying to align the text in the circles in the middle and have them bounce when the circle is hovered(the text that is)

Here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/cJ3se/

Hope someone can help

Denver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to vertically centre a single line of text within an element is to match the 'line-height' to the 'height' of the element. So in this case that would be:

```
.circ {
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

Then, to have the text bounce, simply alter the 'line-height' via an animation:

```
.circ:hover {
    animation: bounce .5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce {
    50% { line-height: 175px; }
}
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/Cvjsu/

Comment: and to make it so it doesn't go past where it starts it just sorta bounces? know what i mean?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but you would just adjust the line-height values in the keyframes to suit.

Comment: Like in this it goes below the initial start point i'd like it to more or less bounce up from that spot then back to it the up then back etc.

Comment: Ah, okay. I have updated my answer, and the link, to reflect this change.